# Copy image contents (not copying two files)

Tags: perl

I'd like to get the contents of `$thumb` into a new, uncreated JPEG file.

Here is my current code:

```
my $path = '/pathtoimage/image.jpg' my $jpg = GD::Image->newFromJpeg( $path, 1 );

my ( $nw, $nh, $x, $y ) = ( 80, 80, 0, 0 );

my ( $ar, $nr ) = ( $w / $h, $nw / $nh );

my ( $ow, $oh ) = ( $nw, $nh );

if ( $ar > $nr ) {
    $nw = int( $w * ( $nh / $h ) );
    $x = int( ( $ow / 2 ) - ( $nw / 2 ) );
}
elsif ( $ar < $nr ) {
    $nh = int( $h * ( $nw / $w ) );
    $y = int( ( $oh / 2 ) - ( $nh / 2 ) );
}

my $string2;
$string2 .= $chars[ rand @chars ] for 1 .. 8;
$string2 = '/path/' . $string2 . '.jpg';

my $thumb = GD::Image->new( $ow, $oh, 1 );
$thumb->copyResampled( $jpg, $x, $y, 0, 0, $nw, $nh, $w, $h );
$thumb->edgeImageSharpen(8);
$thumb->edgeBrightnessContrast( 5, 1.1 );
```

Comment: See the example at https://metacpan.org/pod/GD#Image-Data-Output-Methods

Comment: What if `$ar == $nr`?

Comment: @Borodin I dont know this is not my code im just working with it.

Comment: @slicks1: Then I think you should be doing a lot more than copying someone else's code to Stack Overflow and hoping that we do your job for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the information is in the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~lds/GD-2.56/lib/GD.pm) of the GD module:

> ```
>  # make sure we are writing to a binary stream
> binmode STDOUT;
>
> # Convert the image to PNG and print it on standard output
> print $im->png;
> ```

Instead of having the output in `STDOUT` you want it in a file, and also instead of a `.png` format you prefer a `.jpeg`. Having a look at the [output methods](http://search.cpan.org/~lds/GD-2.56/lib/GD.pm#Image_Data_Output_Methods) of the GD library there is one for JPEG data: `$jpegdata = $image->jpeg([$quality])`.

> **$jpegdata = $image->jpeg([$quality])**
>
> This returns the image data in
>   JPEG format. You can then print it, pipe it to a display program, or
>   write it to a file. You may pass an optional quality score to jpeg()
>   in order to control the JPEG quality. This should be an integer
>   between 0 and 100. Higher quality scores give larger files and better
>   image quality. If you don't specify the quality, jpeg() will choose a
>   good default.

The code you want should be something like:

```
open my $fd, '>', '<path_to_your_new_jpeg>';
binmode $fd;
print $fd $thumb->jpeg(100); # 100 for 100% quality
close $fd;
```

Comment: what exactly is $fd?

Comment: `$fd` is the file descriptor, or filehandle. [What's a file descriptor?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor)

Comment: It's a filehandle. It gets set by the `open` call (like an OUT parameter). See Perl's [tutorial on open](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Documentation for `GD`](http://search.cpan.org/~lds/GD-2.56/lib/GD.pm#Image_Data_Output_Methods), it would seem like you can get the image data in JPEG format using the `jpeg()` method, and can then print that data to a file of your choosing:

```perl
my $jpeg_data = $thumb->jpeg();
open my $jpg_fh, '>', 'new_image.jpg' or die "Could not open: $!\n";
binmode $jpg_fh;
print $jpg_fh $jpeg_data;
close $jpg_fh or die "Could not close: $!\n";
```